# PHP tricky regex to get quoted string up until certain words

Tags: php, regex

I have a variant of strings that look like either of these

```
First rounder 'John Smith' had a good game.

Second rounder 'Jim O'Rielly' is on fire!
```

What I ultimately want is to get both names between quotes `John Smith` and `Jim O'Rielly`, however the tricky part is the names that include apostrophe like the second.

I initially was using `'/\'([^\']*)\'/'` to get the text inside the quotes, but doesn't work for the second case - this would only return `Jim O`.

I then thought to use `.+?(?=had)` in order to get everything up to the word `had`, but it needs to be either `had` or `is`, and I don't want the words `First rounder`, etc.

I need to essentially combine these, so I can get only the text inside the quotes, but UP UNTIL either word `had` or `is`, and I just want the text without quotes.

Unless there is a trick to get the 2nd option ignoring the apostrophe in the name (I thought to addSlashes() but how do I know which apostrophe's to add slashes to?), can anyone suggest a better solution to this ? Bonus points to ignore any special characters that I haven't considering may be found in the name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternate between matching non-`'`s, and matching `'`s *which have word characters on either side*. This way `'`s in the middle of a word will be matched, but `'`s at either end of a word won't.

```
'((?:[^']+|\b'\b)+)'
```

https://regex101.com/r/L9Em5l/1

Comment: A variant with no capture group: `(?<=')(?:[^'\r\n]+|\b'\b)+(?=')`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be matching any char except `'` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

Then only accept matching a `'` if followed by a word boundary and repeat that 0+ so it is optional and also matches a name without a single quote in it.

```
'([^']+(?:'\b[^']++)*)'
```

**Explanation**

- `'(` Match starting `'` and open capture **group 1**

  - `[^']+` Match 1+ times any char except a `'`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `'\b[^']++` Match `'` and word boundary, match 1+ times any char except `'` using a possessive quantifier
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times so this will be optional
- `)'` Close group 1 and match the closing `'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zo6U3Z/1)

If you don't want the negated character class match newlines, you could use `[^'\r\n]+` instead.